# Cakephp 3 Bigint issue - Not receiving the same contact number

Tags: php

> I am working with cakephp 3 and mysql database with a field operator_contact having bigint data type, when i import csv data into my sql database all works good but, not receiving the same contact number as available in the csv sheet. i know if i change the data type of operator_contact field then it will be resolved but the issue is i don't have permission to modify the database or its structure. so is there any solution to get the same output as i expect.

Here i attache the links for screen shots of database table and csv sheet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKZrx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Uvu.png

Thanks

Comment: Storing telephone numbers as integers is just plain wrong - they _are not_ integers. (For example a phone number can start with a `0`, but an integer can not.) So _get_ permission to change the data type, before this causes additional problems down the line.

Comment: ok @CBroe , thanks for suggestion. i will try for the same.